# Why are heading in PFD and map off by exactly 10 degrees?

Tags: navigation, flight-simulator

I was flying on my X-plane 11 flight simulator today and noticed something quite unsettling.

This was a VFR flight between KIAD and KDCA. I pulled up my map for reference and noticed I was flying orthogonal to the map's north direction, even though I was flying a heading of 100.

[image: Juxtaposition: image showing heading indicator and map]

The image shows the map and the PFD for your reference.

**What is going on?** Did I mess with some heading calibration setup? 100 degrees and 90 degrees are perfectly 10 degrees off, so I don't think this has to do with magnetic north issues.

P.S. Strangely, I got to my destination simply following the headings from ATC.

Comment: Winds aloft possibly? One is ground track, the other is heading, they can often be different with wind...

Comment: related (not sure this is a dupe, your question being more specific): [What are the differences between Bearing vs Course vs Direction vs Heading vs Track?](/q/8000/3394)

Comment: another related question: [How to calculations deviation on a magnetic compass and effect of it?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/51529/3394)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KIAD](https://www.airnav.com/airport/KIAD) has a magnetic variation of 10 degrees west, and [KDCA](https://www.airnav.com/airport/KDCA) has a magnetic variation of 11 degrees west, so true vs. magnetic north actually makes sense.

Comment: I'm a little new to navigation.. I could benefit from it if you explain a little more, or redirect me to some answers which address this. I tried a search or two, but couldn't find much.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer I have closed your question as a duplicate of another which will fully explain the difference between true and magnetic north.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks.